# UITableViewCell sometimes showing right information sometimes wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My UITableView is showing some REALLY weird behaviour.

Here is a picture of what is going on:

[image]

Im testing populating the UITableView by adding some information. And every single time for each cell i updated the event to be **Goal** and the player name to be **tet**. Yes every time even for the last 3 cells that you can see is showing some weird behaviour.

after the "10-0" score i decided for the other team to score with the same name tet. First time it shows the image on both sides AND the name is not shown. Second time it shows correctly and third time as you can see it shows wrong again.

**BUT** If i navigate to another view and then go back then everything looks correct as it should.

Here is another example:

[image]

In this example i decide to let each side score every second time with the name "twfr". As you can see it goes wrong in the 5-2 score cell.

I have NO idea to what could be causing this. I tried using this code

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

In 
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

It did work, but you could clearly see when it goes wrong but it quickly changes that and shows wrong ALSO it laggs really much when scrolling. So please guys what could possibly cause this problem?

**EDIT2** Posting more code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        static NSString *identifier = @"MainCell";

        GamesInfoTableViewCell *cell = (GamesInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        //cell.backgroundColor = detailCol;


        [cell.homeTeamLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
        [cell.awayTeamLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];

        cell.gameTimeLabel.textColor = TEXT;
        cell.sectionName.textColor = TEXT;

        cell.liveButton.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LiveButton.png"];

        if ([_GameInfoDictionary[@"time"] isEqualToString:@"FT"])
            cell.liveButton.hidden = TRUE;

        cell.sectionName.text = self.selectedSection;
        cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [self.GameInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"homeTeam"];
        cell.awayTeamLabel.text = _GameInfoDictionary[@"awayTeam"];
        cell.gameTimeLabel.text = _GameInfoDictionary[@"time"];
        cell.homeTeamScoreLabel.text = _GameInfoDictionary[@"homeScore"];
        cell.awayTeamScoreLabel.text = _GameInfoDictionary[@"awayScore"];

        return cell;
    }

    // If its the other section

    static NSString *otherSection = @"events";

    GamesInfoTableViewCell *cell1 = (GamesInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:otherSection];

    cell1.backgroundColor = TABLECOLOR;
    // Configure the cell...
    cell1.gameTimeLabel.textColor = TEXT;
    cell1.homeNameLabel.textColor = TEXT;
    cell1.awayNameLabel.textColor = TEXT;



    // Select the event object for the specefik row
    NSMutableDictionary *gameInfoObject =[_events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Seperate event and name
    NSArray * array = [gameInfoObject[@"eventType"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString * typeEvent = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * nameOfPlayer = [array objectAtIndex:1];

    UIImage *imageType;

    //Change the typeofevent name here to goal so it matches with the image name,
    // Set the name of the event same as the picture to load correct image
    NSMutableString *eventNameToImage = [NSMutableString string];
    [eventNameToImage appendString:typeEvent];
    [eventNameToImage appendString:@".png"];

    imageType = [UIImage imageNamed:eventNameToImage];

    if ([typeEvent isEqualToString:goal]  || [typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyGoal] || [typeEvent isEqualToString:owngoal] )
        cell1.bothScoreLabel.text = gameInfoObject[@"eventScore"];

    else
        cell1.bothScoreLabel.hidden = YES;

    cell1.gameTimeLabel.text = gameInfoObject[@"eventTime"];

    if ([gameInfoObject[@"selectedTeam"] isEqualToString:@"homeTeam"])
    {
        cell1.homeNameLabel.text = nameOfPlayer;
        cell1.awayNameLabel.hidden = YES;
        cell1.homeTeamImage.image = imageType;

        if([typeEvent isEqualToString:owngoal]){
            [cell1.homeOwnGoalLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:7]];
            cell1.homeOwnGoalLabel.hidden = NO;
        }

        else if([typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyGoal] || [typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyMiss])
            cell1.homeNameLabel.text = [cell1.homeNameLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@" (str.)"];
    }

    else
    {
        cell1.awayNameLabel.text = nameOfPlayer;
        cell1.homeNameLabel.hidden = YES;
        cell1.awayTeamImage.image = imageType;

        if([typeEvent isEqualToString:owngoal]){
            [cell1.awayOwnGoalLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:7]];
            cell1.awayOwnGoalLabel.hidden = NO;
        }

        else if([typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyGoal] || [typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyMiss])
            cell1.awayNameLabel.text = [cell1.awayNameLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@" (str.)"];
    }

    //[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    return cell1;
}
```

Comment: Don't reload the rows inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`!

Comment: Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code?

Comment: @AaronBrager just added. Its alot :P

Comment: `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` calls `cellForRowsAtIndexPath` you should not reload inside that method

Comment: I just tried it to see if it fixed the problem. I had a feeling that it was not good to use it there

Comment: if you have any question regarding the code please feel free to ask. @AaronBrager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you're not accounting for the fact that cells are reused. When you get `cell`, it might already have data set on it from a previous call.

For example, here:

```
if ([gameInfoObject[@"selectedTeam"] isEqualToString:@"homeTeam"])
{
    cell1.homeNameLabel.text = nameOfPlayer;
    cell1.awayNameLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell1.homeTeamImage.image = imageType;

    if([typeEvent isEqualToString:owngoal]){
        [cell1.homeOwnGoalLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:7]];
        cell1.homeOwnGoalLabel.hidden = NO;
    }

    else if([typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyGoal] || [typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyMiss])
        cell1.homeNameLabel.text = [cell1.homeNameLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@" (str.)"];
}

else
{
    cell1.awayNameLabel.text = nameOfPlayer;
    cell1.homeNameLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell1.awayTeamImage.image = imageType;

    if([typeEvent isEqualToString:owngoal]){
        [cell1.awayOwnGoalLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:7]];
        cell1.awayOwnGoalLabel.hidden = NO;
    }

    else if([typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyGoal] || [typeEvent isEqualToString:penaltyMiss])
        cell1.awayNameLabel.text = [cell1.awayNameLabel.text stringByAppendingString:@" (str.)"];
}
```

You set `homeTeamImage` in one case, but don't set it in the other case.

You need to set all variables in all cases, because otherwise they will retain their values from the last time this cell object was displayed.

Alternatively, you can implement `prepareForReuse` in your `UITableViewCell` subclass and reset everything to a default value there, but that may hurt performance.

Comment: so setting hometeamimage to be hidden would resolve that issue ? in the else case?

Comment: Also one more thing, Ur saying that it can use values from last time. There is no cell that has no name on it. why would the name be empty sometimes then? Makes no sense

Comment: Set `hidden` to `YES` or set the image to `nil`.

Comment: Perhaps you see that behavior because you're hiding the label.

Comment: So hiding wont make things better?, Is it better to set stuff nil then?

Comment: added a few more lines of code where i specify what should be hidden or not and it worked. thnx !!! saved my life